# Sideloading conditionally with ActiveModel::Serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, active-model-serializers

I'm building an API using **ActiveModel::Serializers**. What is the best way to sideload data conditionally using params?

So I can make requests like `GET /api/customers`:

```
"customers": {
   "first_name": "Bill",
   "last_name": "Gates"
}
```

And `GET /api/customers?embed=address,note`

```
"customers": {
   "first_name": "Bill",
   "last_name": "Gates"
},
"address: {
   "street": "abc"
},
"note": {
   "body": "Banned"
}
```

Something like that depending on the params. I know ActiveModel::Serializers has the `include_[ASSOCIATION]?` syntax but how can I use it efficiently from my controllers?

---

This is my current solution, but it's not neat:

**customer_serializer.rb:**

```
def include_address?
  !options[:embed].nil? && options[:embed].include?(:address)
end
```

**application_controller.rb:**

```
def embed_resources(resources = [])
  params[:embed].split(',').map { |x| resources << x.to_sym } if params[:embed]
  resources
end
```

**customers_controller.rb:**

```
def show
  respond_with @customer, embed: embed_resources
end
```

Must be an easier way?

Answer (score 8):

I'm also looking for an effective and clean way to do this.

I found a solution but it's not pretty.

In my BaseController/ApplicationController I added this method:

```
serialization_scope :params
```

So the scope is now the params Hash and I can use it in the `include_[ASSOCIATION]?` methods of my serializers.

```
def include_associations?
    if scope[:embed]
        embed = scope[:embed].split(',') 
        return true if embed.include?('associations')
    end
end
```

I don't like this method because if I need to use the scope for something else like the `current_user` to conditionally return data if it's an admin for instance.

But this solution can work in some cases.

**UPDATE**

You can pass `view_context` instead of directly pass the `params`.

And you can delegate in your Serializer to keep the `params` name instead of `scope`.

in your ApplicationController:

```
serialization_scope :view_context
```

in your serializer:

```
delegate :params, to: :scope
```

And voila you can use params[:embed] in the `include_[ASSOCIATION]?` methods of your serializers.

Comment: I like your suggestions using view_context. Is it possible to unit test this with rspec?

Comment: I've updated my question to show you how I have been doing it.

Answer (score 2):

I have yet another solution based off of your answers because I wanted similar functionality. According to the documentation if one wants lower level control of association serialization, they can override `include_associations!`.

For example:

```
def include_associations!
    if scope[:embed]
        include! :addresses, {embed: :ids, include: true}
    else
        include! :addresses, {embed: :ids}
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Very helpful to know about include_associations!, thanks! Noting that with the active_model_serializers gem (version 0.8.3) you can use `@options` to set context in the controller. For example, if in the controller you call

```
render json: customer, include_addresses: true
```

then in CustomerSerializer:

```
has_many :addresses
def include_associations!
  if @options[:include_addresses]
    include! :addresses
  end
end
```

then the addresses will be serialized. If you render with `include_addresses` set to `false`, they won't be.
With newer versions of active_model_serializers, use `serialization_options` rather than `@options`.